# Can I delete a tag signed by somebody else?

Tags: git, tags, gnupg

Is it possible to delete a gpg signed tag on a remote repository without having the key?  I expect the answer is no, but is this true?

Another way to phrase the question:  Is it possible to put permissions on tags?  Or do I need gitosis for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can delete any tag, branch or commit on the remote repo as git repos do not have any authorization checks themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delete a gpg signed tag much like normal tags:

```
git tag -d tag1
git push origin :refs/tags/tag1
```